# Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC application and use dependency injection and repository pattern to inject a repository into my controller.

However, I am getting an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPyIh.png)

EfCategoryDal:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtTxT.png)

Generic repository:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNzDB.png)

`CategoryManager`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrGXE.png)

`ICategoryService`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDrLy.png)

`CategoryController`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDvqV.png)

`Startup`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUrt1.png)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but code and error messages must be included in the question as text, not images. You should not include more code than necessary to demonstrate the issue either. Try and create a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue in a concise way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the Context type in your configure service, let me know the result

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>();
```